# Is there a way in Angular to display code snippets in HTML page?

Tags: angular

I am trying to show static code in a web page.
Is there a way in Angular to display code snippets in an HTML page?

Comment: in witch editor you used

Comment: Are you trying to show static code in your web page?

Comment: @Arcteezy yes..

Comment: Have you tried the `code` tag?

Comment: If you use VScode then you can install Angular Snippets by John Papa

Answer (score 14):

I think what you are looking for is [ngx-highlightjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-highlightjs).

It can auto-detect languages, easy to install and customize via css, has multiple themes etc.

Check out their [demo site](https://ngx-highlight.netlify.com/).

Answer (score 5):

In your html code

```
<pre>
  <code [innerHTML]="code"></code>
</pre>
 Java Code 
<pre>
  <code [innerHTML]="java_code"></code>
</pre>
```

In typescript file

```
code = `
export model = new Model({
  a:1,
  b:function(){}
})
`;

  java_code = `
  public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
  }
 `;
```

Try [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-display-code-snippets-in-html-page)

Answer (score 3):

There is no need of any external libraries to show code snippets in web pages. You can simply leverage the `code` or `pre` tags. Store the snippets as string and use the variable for display.

**app.component.ts** :

```
snippet = 
`function test(){
  console.log('Test');
}`
```

**app.component.html** :

```
<pre>{{snippet}}</pre>

<code>{{snippet}}</code>
```

Both `code` and `pre` shows snippets in same format but, only `pre` provides formatting with line breaks.

Demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qvfk4u